# Calculator's Script wrong counts the ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue. I have a simple calculator script and the script started to calculate incorrectly. If I type "1000" it calculates right ($10) and if I type 50000 it calculates right as well ($380). But if I type 10000 it calculates wrong.

The ranges are:

```
0 – 1000 = $0.01
10000 – 10000 = $0.009
10000 – 25000 = $0.0084
25000 – 50000 = $0.0076
50000+ = $0.0076
```

Unfortunately I'm not a Javascript expert so I will appreciate for your help.

```js
function priceCalculation(a){
    if(a <= 1000){
        return 0.001;
    }else if(a >= 1001 && a <= 10000 ){
        return 0.009;
    }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
        return 0.0084;
    }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
        return 0.0076;
    }else{
        return 0.0076;
    }
}

// number format set to en-US e.g (from 1500 to 1,500)
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

$('#likecount').keyup(function(e){
    // if a '.' is pressed
 if($(this).val().endsWith('.')) {
     return;
    }

    // if input value is empty then assign '0' else the original value
    var inputVal = $(this).val() === ''?'0':$(this).val();
  
    inputVal = parseFloat(inputVal.replace(/[$|,]/g, ''));
    var price = priceCalculation($(this).val());
    var total = (inputVal * price);
    total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    var formatted = numFormat.format(inputVal) // set format to input
    $(this).val(formatted); // display the formatted input back
    $('#output').text((total)); // display the total price
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="How many Instagram likes?" style="height: 50px;width: 360px;color: #222;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px #85c9e3 solid;font-size: 18px;" type="text" id="likecount" />
<p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Pricing: <b><span style="color: #004f04;"> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b></p>
```

Comment: When you enter `10,000` it is taking the input as `1,0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is invalid.

```
var price = priceCalculation($(this).val());
```

`$(this).val()` returns a string. When you have `,` in it (on thousands), it causes to call your `priceCalculation` function and return the last `else` statement which is `return 0.0076;`

Since you already have `inputVal` that you have parsed into number, you can use it like,

```
var price = priceCalculation(inputVal);
```

Final result,

```js
function priceCalculation(a) {
  if (a <= 1000) {
    return 0.001;
  } else if (a >= 1001 && a <= 10000) {
    return 0.009;
  } else if (a >= 10001 && a <= 25000) {
    return 0.0084;
  } else if (a >= 25001 && a <= 50000) {
    return 0.0076;
  } else {
    return 0.0076;
  }
}

// number format set to en-US e.g (from 1500 to 1,500)
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

$('#likecount').keyup(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().endsWith('.')) {
    return;
  }
  
  var inputVal = $(this).val() === '' ? '0' : $(this).val();

  inputVal = parseFloat(inputVal.replace(/[$|,]/g, ''));
  var price = priceCalculation(inputVal);
  var total = (inputVal * price);
  total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  var formatted = numFormat.format(inputVal);
  $(this).val(formatted);
  $('#output').text((total));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="How many Instagram likes?" style="height: 50px;width: 360px;color: #222;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px #85c9e3 solid;font-size: 18px;" type="text" id="likecount" />
<p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Pricing: <b><span style="color: #004f04;"> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a little mistake

```js
function priceCalculation(a){
    if(a <= 1000){
        return 0.001;
    }else if(a >= 1001 && a <= 10000 ){
        return 0.009;
    }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
        return 0.0084;
    }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
        return 0.0076;
    }else{
        return 0.0076;
    }
}

// number format set to en-US e.g (from 1500 to 1,500)
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

$('#likecount').keyup(function(e){
    // if a '.' is pressed
 if($(this).val().endsWith('.')) {
     return;
    }

    // if input value is empty then assign '0' else the original value
    var inputVal = $(this).val() === ''?'0':$(this).val();
  
    inputVal = parseFloat(inputVal.replace(/[$|,]/g, ''));
    var price = priceCalculation(inputVal);  //a little mistake ;D
    var total = (inputVal * price);
    total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    var formatted = numFormat.format(inputVal) // set format to input
    $(this).val(formatted); // display the formatted input back
    $('#output').text((total)); // display the total price
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="How many Instagram likes?" style="height: 50px;width: 360px;color: #222;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px #85c9e3 solid;font-size: 18px;" type="text" id="likecount" />
<p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Pricing: <b><span style="color: #004f04;"> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b></p>
```